# undefined method `default_scoped?' while accessing scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, named-scope

I am getting this error while accessing scopes.

Here is AR model

```
class StatisticVariable < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :name

  has_many  :statistic_values

  scope :logins, where(code: 'logins').first
  scope :unique_logins, where(code: 'unique_logins').first
  scope :registrations, where(code: 'registrations').first

end
```

and when I try with `StatisticVariable.logins` or any other scopes it gives:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?'
```

If I configure scope as class method then it works perfectly.

```
def self.registrations
    where(code: 'registrations').first
end
```

Please guide me to understand and fix this problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your so called `scopes` are not scopes: they aren't chainable.

I guess Rails tries to append a potential `default_scope` to your result which leads to failure.

Do something like:

```
  scope :logins, where(code: 'logins')
  scope :unique_logins, where(code: 'unique_logins')
  scope :registrations, where(code: 'registrations')

  def self.login
    logins.first
  end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for this! I got this when changing `default_scope order: "foo"` to `default_scope { { order: "foo" } }`. Fixed it by changing it to `default_scope { order("foo") }`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because one of my scopes was returning `self`, which I assumed was the relation object (didn't work); returning `nil` instead achieved the expected result. eg:

```
scope :except_ids, -> ids do
  if ids.present?
    ids = ids.split(',') if ids.respond_to?(:split)
    where('id not in (?)', ids)
  end
end
```

if ids.present? returns false, the condition returns nil and the scope has no effect, but is still chainable.