# Complex Find conditions to return one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am querying my booking model to get details, including a list of has_many appointments.

To do this I'm using a scope:

```
scope :current_cart, 
Booking.includes(:appointments).where(:parent_id => 1).where(:complete =>nil).order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

Then in the view:

```
<%  @booking.appointments.each do |appointment| %>
  # info output
<% end %>
```

To get this working, in the controller, I have to do this:

```
@booking = Booking.current_cart[0]
```

It's the [0] bit i'm worried about.  I guess I'm using a method that wants to return a collection, and that means i have to state that i want the first (only) record.  How can i state a similar scope that is more appropriate to fetch a member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding .first or [0] to the scope gives error:

```
undefined method `default_scoped?' for
```

googling that gave this:
[undefined method `default_scoped?' while accessing scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365128/undefined-method-default-scoped-while-accessing-scope)

So apparently adding .first or [0] stops it being chainable, so it gives an error. using that answer, i did:

```
  scope :open_carts, 
   Booking.includes(:appointments).where(:parent_id => 1)
   .where(:complete =>nil).order("created_at DESC")

  def self.current_cart
   open_carts.first
  end
```

Little bit messy, but i'd prefer mess in my model, and it isn't nonsensical to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Try tacking ".first" onto the end of the scope.  Scopes are just regular AREL queries, and so you can use any standard methods as you normally would.