# map in scope in active record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, padrino

I have a active record, where I have a usecase: I want to use `map` in the `ActiveRecord` `scopes`. Following is my code:

```
class SupportedGeoIdAndLocation < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :supported_geo_ids,            lambda { all.map(&:geo_id).uniq }
   # also tried: scope :supported_geo_ids,            lambda { select('distinct geo_id').map(&:geo_id).uniq }
   scope :locations_for_geo_id, lambda { |geo_id| where(:geo_id => geo_id).map(&:location) }
end
```

but when I do `SupportedGeoIdAndLocation.supported_geo_ids` I get empty array, while `SupportedGeoIdAndLocation.all.map(&:geo_id).uniq` gives me desired result.

I am looking for a way so that this can be done using lambda in one go, not via chaining of different methods and completely avoiding class functions.

Looks like I am using scope in wrong way, Please suggest me what can be correct way.

version: `padrino`:0.10.5, `ruby`: ruby-1.9.3-p429, `ActiveRecord`: 3.1.6

Comment: you no need `map` use `pluck`, `scope :supported_geo_ids,            lambda { pluck(:geo_id) }`

Comment: I am in older version of rails and pluck is not defined in this version.

Comment: are you using padrino or rails...?

Comment: @sevenseacat: I am using `Padrino`.

Comment: @saurabh: As `Padrino` tries to be database agnostic it is not tied to a specific version of `ActiveRecord`, could you provide the output of your `bundle show activerecord`?

Comment: @Patru: It is activerecord-3.1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with some similar code in one of my models I finally found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365128/undefined-method-default-scoped-while-accessing-scope) (as I got the same error message (in Rails 3.2 that was)). The accepted answer states that `ActiveRecord` implicitly assumes `scopes` to be "chainable" (in `ARel` sense) which the array you return obviously is not.

So while you can do whatever you want in a class method you define yourself (as in the answer of @xdazz) you will have to adhere to `ActiveRecord` conventions if you insist on using `scope` (which at first glance just defines a class method with whatever `lambda` you provided it). There seems to be more to this than I could spot.

**Update**

After some more fiddling I think I got as close as it gets. You *can* write a `scope` that returns just supported geo ids, i.e. as follows:

```
class SupportedGeoIdAndLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :supported_geo_ids,  lambda { select("distinct(geo_id)") }
end
```

However that will return an `ARel` relation that can be turned into an array of `SupportedGeoIdAndLocation` objects with just the `geo_id` attribute set (and, sorry to disappoint you, it *is* a class method, even if it ends up being defined through the `scope` class method). So if you *need* an array of attributes you can turn it into one using the method you proposed in another class method:

```
class SupportedGeoIdAndLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.geo_ids_array
    supported_geo_ids.map(&:geo_id)
  end
end
```

Note that there is no need to call `uniq` now as this has been taken care of by the `distinct` in the `scope`. Up from rails 4.0.2 `ActiveRecord` does support the `distinct` method by the way, so you won't have to resort to using a string if you can update your `ActiveRecord` gem as `Padrino` should not depend on it.

Answer (score 5):

`scope` should return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so scope could be chained with another scope or class methods etc.

If you want to get an array, use class method instead.

```
def self.supported_geo_ids
  all.map(&:geo_id).uniq
end
```

Comment: Yes that will work. But why `scope` returns an *empty relation* ?

Comment: Actually, I was hoping there is some feature ruby have, and I dont have to use chaining or use class methods for this.

Answer (score 3):

As @patru pointed out, scopes are only meant to return relations. They are not meant to return values. Therefore, your question "how do I make a scope return a particular value?" is unanswerable.

My impression is that you think that class methods are poor design, or not "The Rails Way", but in this case, I agree with @xdazz that they are the best solution.

However, I would implement the method slightly differently:

```
def self.supported_geo_ids
  self.all(:select => "DISTINCT(geo_id)").map(&:geo_id)
end
```

That way, de-duplicating is performed in the database engine, and only the required values are returned. This makes the query potentially much faster.

In newer versions of Rails, you would write it like this:

```
def self.supported_geo_ids
  self.uniq.pluck(:geo_id)
end
```

If for some reason you still don't want to use a class method, please explain why and I'll try to think of a workaround.